# Laravel 8.x Signed URL within Azure App Service (PHP 8.0.27 + Nginx)

Tags: php, laravel, azure, nginx, php-8

Locally, I have my `.env` configuration file property `APP_URL` assocaiated to a custom DNS record of `https://some-project.local`

I then do the following to create a temporary signed URL:

```
$temporaryUrl = URL::temporarySignedRoute('temp.download', now()->addHours(24), ($struct = [
    'uid' => Str::uuid()->toString(),
    // ...
]));
```

Later, in my `temp.download` route I do the following:

```
public function tempDownload(string $uuid, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasValidSignature()) {
        abort(401);
    }
}
```

Locally, this is working fine. When I deploy this into development/testing/production environments inside Azure, it always hits 401.

I have updated my configuration to contain the `APP_URL` and have asserted this via a SSH session running `artisan tinker`:

```
Psy Shell v0.11.8 (PHP 8.0.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> env('APP_URL')
=> "https://XXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net"
```

It appears that the SSL termination inside Azure from the load balancer is screwing the signature. For this, I updated the `TrustProxies` as suggested by multiple SO questions and the docs to the following:

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{

    protected $proxies = '*';
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

This, however, is still causing the 401 to hit. Any help appreciated on how I can get signed URL's to work inside Azure.

My NGINX configuration for the PHP-FPM pass from Nginx looks like this:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    # Custom Azure configuration to support laravel
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    # Azure pre-defined
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;

    # Buffers
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 512k;

    # Server hardening
    fastcgi_hide_header "x-powered-by";
}
```

Do I need to set anything in the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header to achieve this in Azure?

> It is important to note that I use `server _;` as I have multiple servers (dev/test/prod) so I do not target one specific domain in my NGINX config.

**Update** - Doing some debug in Azure, I added the following route:

```
# Also tried 'X-Forwarded-Host'
Route::any('/test', fn(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) => [$request->header('X-FORWARDED-HOST')]);
```

Which returns `[null]`, this leads me to think I need some sort of Nginx configuration to make this work?

Also, if I `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` I can see the IP being logged is always the [link-local address of the proxy (169.254.XXX.X)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927). I think all of this just needs tweeking inside Nginx so FPM sees the correct values - how can I do this dynamically based on the `server _` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue I had was that locally, this didn't technically work.

In my NGINX configuration, I force a `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` header in the requests to enable local debug from the mobile application etc.

This lead to me using the WRONG syntax locally, I was missing the `!` operator:

```
if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) {
    abort(401);
}
```

This lead to Azure working but not my local so I instead wrote this function to ignore additional params for local dev:

```
private function hasValidSignature(): bool
{
    $url = rtrim(request()->url() . '?' . Arr::query(Arr::except(request()->query(), ['signature', 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START'])), '?');
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $url, app()->make('config')->get('app.key'));

    return hash_equals($signature, (string) request()->query('signature')) && !(now()->getTimestamp() > (string) request()->query('expires'));
}
```